# Launch application via ssh

Tags: ssh, rhythmbox, nohup

I am new to SSH. I can connect to a remote computer.
I can also launch an application on a remote computer and see its GUI on my screen.

But I do not know how to launch an application without it producing output on my screen.

I want to launch an application (eg. rhythmbox), and close the ssh connection, leaving the application running, without sending any output to my screen.

Surfing the web I have found some advice, but nothing helped me;

```
ssh -X name@domain
nohup rhythmbox &
logout
```

Comment: You may need to play with the DISPLAY environment variable to force the GUI to display on an X Display that will not terminate when the connection is closed. In addition you would need nohup. What are you trying to accomplish firing up a GUI you cannot see?

Comment: Let me see if I've understood correctly. You want to connect from your laptop to your desktop, for instance, launch a music player which would then appear on the desktop and not on the laptop? In other words; you'd like to use another computer as a sort of remote control?

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you want Rhythmbox to display onto the remote computer's screen? The screen onto which a GUI application is displayed is indicated by the `DISPLAY` environment variable. When you run `ssh -X`, `DISPLAY` is set to a value that indicates that display requests must be forwarded over the SSH connection. To make the application display on the remote computer's screen, set `DISPLAY` to the value `:0`.

```
ssh username@example.com 'DISPLAY=:0 rhythmbox &'
```

There's one more hurdle: when an application connects to an X display, it needs to provide a sort of password called a cookie. The cookie is generated each time the X server starts. Ubuntu stores the cookie in a file with a randomly generated name. The easiest way to find the cookie is to store it in a well-known file name when the X server starts. On Ubuntu, add this code to your `~/.profile`:

```
case $DISPLAY:$XAUTHORITY in
  :*:?*)
    # DISPLAY is set and points to a local display, and XAUTHORITY is
    # set, so merge the contents of `$XAUTHORITY` into ~/.Xauthority.
    XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority xauth merge "$XAUTHORITY";;
esac
```

For more background, see [ssh DISPLAY variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126).

---

Or did you mean you never ever want to see the Rhythmbox window? If so, make it connect to a virtual X server, [xvfb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xvfb) [image: Install xvfb]. Start the virtual X server, then tell Rhythmbox to connect to it.

```
ssh username@example.com 'Xvfb :1 -screen 0 800x600x8 & sleep 1; DISPLAY=:1 rhythmbox &'
```

Comment: Anyway, in case of remote audio player on the local X server (`-X` option to ssh), where the sound will go?

Comment: @enzotib The sound will be played locally, unless you've set up sound forwarding (unless recent versions of Ubuntu set up sound forwarding by default?).

Comment: You should probably use nohup or run the Rhythmbox in a screen session. Otherwise, when you close the terminal window on the client, Rhythmbox will be terminated on the server as well.